# How to read content of socket stream in PHP stream socket server

Tags: php, sockets

I'm looking for solution to read and process message from stream within created socket server.

I've come to this:

```
$server = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:8000", $errno, $errorMessage);

for (;;) 
{
    $client = @stream_socket_accept($server);

    if ($client) 
    {
        echo 'Connection accepted from '.stream_socket_get_name($client, false) . "n";


        stream_copy_to_stream($client, $client);
        fclose($client);
    }
}
```

which simply echoes whatever is sent to stream. I cannot find out what do I need to do, say, between `stream_socket_accept()` and `fclose()` to get contents of message and act upon it. Any help? Thanks in advance.